Parsing COBOL Style Syntax using Regex
I am expending my COBOL like parser to extract the target of a Move statement but not anything is square brackets after the element i.e. It should not match the element [B]. An example of the code I am parsing is
        Move GLB.SPACES[B]      GG_EWE.GG_EWE_IN.GP_EWE_FOCUS
        Move 0                  GG_EWE.GG_EWE_IN.GP_EWE_PRIORITY
        Move "667"              GG_EWE.GG_EWE_IN.GP_EWE_CODE
        Move "CUS01"            GG_EWE.GG_EWE_IN.GP_EWE_SOURCE[A]
        Move "Invalid customer type's for this screen"      GG_EWE.GG_EWE_IN.GP_EWE_DESC

In each case I only want the target of the Move. I currently have the expression
(?<=\bMove\s+(?:""(.*?)"")|(?:\.\w+)*(\[\w+\])?\s+)\w+(?:\.\w+)

but this is matching the element GLB.SPACES[B] and only the first two elements of the target. i.e it matches GG_EWE.GG_EWE_IN but not GG_EWE.GG_EWE_IN.GP_EWE_PRIORITY. In theory there could be any number of elemets here (A.B.C.D.E etc) Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.
My current thoughts are at https://regex101.com/r/iAdfVr/1
Thanks

Do mean like this? (?<=\bMove\s+(?:(?:""[^""]*""|\w+(?:\.\w+)*\[\w+]|\d+)\s+)?)\w+(?:\.\w+)* https://regex101.com/r/HwJG3z/1

Thanks for the quick reply but that still looks to be matching the source elements GLB.SPACES and 0. Not sure what is wrong as the ""[^""]"" looks to be in the non capturing element.

If you don't want to match those, then (?<=\bMove\s+(?:(?:""[^""]*""|\w+(?:\.\w+)*\[\w+]|\d+)\s+))\w+(?:\.\w+)* https://regex101.com/r/gkKYaj/1

Check the following regex (?<=\bMove\b\s+(?:\S+\s+)+)(\w+(?:\.\w+)*)(?=(?:\[.+?\])?$) https://regex101.com/r/GXCq2e/1

Please define "target". Whenever you give an example, please show the desired result.

Thanks to The Fourth Bird and Andrei - that works perfectly.

Cary - The target of the Move statement is the right hand variable. e.g. In MOVE A B, B is the target

If you're writing a parser and you require detailed control over the specific leading format prior to matching, you could use:
(?<=\bMove\s+(?:"[^"]*"|\w+(?:\.\w+)*\[\w+]|\d+)\s+)\w+(?:\.\w+)*


(?<= Positive lookbehind, assert that what is to the left is

\bMove\s+ Match the word Move and 1+ whitespace chars
(?: Non capture group for the alternatives:

"[^"]*" Match "..."
| Or
\w+(?:\.\w+)*\[\w+] Match 1+ word chars,optionally repeat matching . and 1+ word chars and then match 1+ word chars between square brackets
| Or
\d+ Match 1+ digits


) Close the non capture group
\s+ Match 1+ whitespace chars


) Close the lookbehind
\w+(?:\.\w+)* Match 1+ word chars and optionally repeat matching . and 1+ word chars

See a regex demo and a .NET Regex demo with the doubled ""
